# Simple ng-show animation is not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I am trying to reproduce the ng-show animation from angularjs documentation

```
<div class="v3-account-form animate-show-hide" ng-show="thing.shown">
   <h3>{{thing.id}}</h3>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.animate-show-hide.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

.animate-show-hide.ng-hide-add,
.animate-show-hide.ng-hide-remove {
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

.v3-account-form {
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

But the animation is not working here is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/ffKTy/527/

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ffKTy/528/)? Note that you need to include [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) in your app

Answer (score 1):

You didn't import in your Fiddle [`ngAnimate`](//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-animate.js). As you can see in the Angular [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Bk6mINEPDHKapsAO3rsp?p=preview), it is necessary to make there ngShow animation work.

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-animate.js"></script>
```